# Tangent Space of a Submanifold

Tags: general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have been reading through some material on submanifolds and have come across the following exercise which I'm having trouble understanding:

Let $M$ be a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $x\in M$. Let $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth curve: $\gamma(t)$ is a smooth map.  $\gamma'(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n_{\gamma(t)}$ is the tangent vector of $\gamma$ at $t$. Show that the tangent space $M_x$ consists of all tangent vectors at $0$ of curves $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(t)\in M\;\forall t\in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ and $\gamma(0)=x$.

I am having trouble understanding what the question is asking and how I would go about approaching it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: The tangent space is typically defined by what you have written above. Was there another definition that it is perhaps asking you to prove equivalence to?

Comment: It is from lecture notes which are based on Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Comment: There is no other definition. This is why I was confused, it seems like I am being asked to show a definition?

Comment: Very strange...that is just the definition of tangent space at $x$

Comment: There are a variety of ways that the tangent bundle can be defined. A different one is that $M_x$ is the space of lebnitzian operators on the sheaf of functions on $M$ about $x$. However, I don't know which definition Spivak uses.